# Turning multiple excel arrays into two columns using python

Tags: python, excel, loops, transpose

I have the following a series of columns and rows in Excel that look similar to the below (I'll mention that I have a significant number of columns and rows and this is a simplified example)

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  7  6
2  7  9
3     1
4     0
      1
```

I am looking for a python function that would take those columns and turn them into the following two columns:

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 4
B 2
B 7
C 7
C 9
C 1
C 0
C 1
D 6
```

Essentially, creating a separate row for each number under the first row and repeating the letter.

I have created a VBA function but unfortunately it is taking way too long.

Comment: Please include some of your data and more explanations for MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `import pandas as pd; pd.read_excel("in.xlsx").melt().dropna().to_excel("out.xlsx)` ?